# Issue while Authorize an salesforce org in VS Code failed, due to Invalid request method: OPTION

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, authorization

I have installed VS code, Salesforce CLI with extensions, and Java.

I have created the project. After that, I tried to authorize an org in vs code. But I faced the issue as

> Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org
>
> 20:41:47.938 sfdx org:login:web --alias Trialhead --instance-url
> https://login.salesforce.com --set-default Error (1): Invalid request
> method: OPTIONS
>
> 20:42:12.795 sfdx org:login:web --alias Trialhead --instance-url
> https://login.salesforce.com --set-default  ended with exit code 1

I tried to find the solution for so many hours. I couldn't find anything. I came across the CORS and HTTP OPTIONS request. But I don't know what to do to resolve this blocker.

Kindly someone help me with this.

SF CLI Version -- `C:\Users\manoj>sf --version@salesforce/cli/2.30.8 win32-x64 node-v20.11.1`

I have done following things in VS Code while trying to solve this issue.

> Salesforcedx-vscode-apex › Java: Home = C:\Program Files\Zulu\zulu-17
>
> Salesforcedx-vscode-core: NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS = C:\Program Files\sf\bin\sfdx

Comment: What if you try the same command directly in terminal,  with --debug at the end ?

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I got the same issue. Is it my side or what do I need to do? This is a big blocker for me.

Comment: It's probably on your side :/
Are you behind a proxy, or do you have an angry firewall that would block JWT listener ?

Comment: I have same for sandboxes

Answer (score 2):

try this command :

```
sfdx auth:device:login -a dev-sandboxname -r https://test.salesforce.com -s
```

And then enter the code given in the CLI

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was logging into the org on the browser, then running `sfdx force:auth:device:login`. It will provide you with a code and a verification URL. After pasting the code, you'll be able to select the org and deploy to it etc

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when trying to login from different browser than one opened by sfdx.

I normally default to Safari, but use Brave for work. When login prompt appears I would just paste login url to Brave and it worked until few days ago.

Edit looks like Chrome is to blame here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2785